# Finding the exact value of $\sin^{-1}$

Tags: trigonometry

I have a question that says to find the exact value of $\sin^{-1} (1/\sqrt{2})$

For the answer it shows $\frac{\pi}{4} \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Where does that last part in [] comes from? What is it? $\pi/4$ is $45$ degrees, I understand how they get that part but not the other.

Comment: $\frac{\pi}{4} \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$?

Comment: Yea, that's what I intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe seems to be
$$ \frac{\pi}{4} \in \left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right] $$

$x \in A$ means that $x$ is a member of the set $A$.

$[a,b]$, "the closed interval $a$, $b$" means the set of real numbers between, or equal to one of, $a$ and $b$, i.e.
$$ [a,b] = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} : a \leqslant x \leqslant b \}. $$

Comment: Ohhhh ok. I seen now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of sine inverse, $\sin^{-1}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = \theta \iff \sin \theta = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$. Only one angle that satisfies this: $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ or $45^{\circ}$.

The part $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ means that $\theta$ is greater than $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, and is less than $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: $\theta \in \left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ I still don't get what this part is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Gave it Chappers cause they got to it first though.

Comment: The range of $f(x) = \arcsin x$ is $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$ rather than $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ since $\arcsin(1) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\arcsin(-1) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.